# How to know how many element the string array include?

Tags: c, arrays

I have a code can printf all of the string element like

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char * c[]={"I love you.","I don't."};
    char **p = c;
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++) //I judge the number is 2 by my eyes
        printf("%s\n",*p++);
    return 0;
}
```

But I don't like that part that I just can know the number is `2` by my eyes.Is there any elegant method can know how many element the array `c` contain?A in-built function maybe name `count` is ecpected in this post.Such as `count(c)` can give me the `2`.

Comment: May be [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c) could help you

Comment: `sizeof c/sizeof *c` is a good start.

Comment: @chux You method can apply to a `int` array.But in a string array,every element take up different space.

Comment: @yode The elements of the array are *pointers* not *strings*. Pointers take up constant space.

Comment: @yode - for `char *c[]` that doesn't matter.  `sizeof(c)` gives the size of an array of pointers, and `sizeof(*c)` gives the size of a pointer (i.e. a `char *`).   The initialisation of those pointers doesn't affect that.

Comment: @yode Useful site:  [declare c as array of pointer to char](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+*+c%5B%5D)